# What is the difference between past perfect and past simple

Tags: verbs, past-perfect, past-simple

I have always been confused about when to use **past simple** and when to use **past perfect**

These examples:

> Aren't they the ones who had come over for lunch?
>
> Aren't they the ones who came over for lunch

What is the difference between these two?

What is the difference between past perfect and past simple

Comment: This could help : https://www.grammarly.com/blog/past-perfect/

Answer (score 0):

It's more like 
An event described in simple past tense happened earlier than the event described in past perfect.
And we can describe the events in past perfect in sequence.
Example: We chose him as he had scored well marks.

https://www.grammarly.com/blog/past-perfect/

https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/everyday-grammar-simple-past-and-present-perfect/2752310.html